# IntelliJ IDEA - java: error: invalid source release: 18

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I got the error while building.

[image]

Comment: You are using JDK 1.8 and trying to use language level 18, go to the project settings and change it to 8.

Answer (score 10):

Your project uses java 8 (denoted by 1.8) but your IDE is having Java 18.
Upgrade your project to java 18 or change settings in your IDE to Java 8

Comment: My project is based on Java 18 so I installed Java SDK 18 then setting up File | **Project Structure** | **Platform Settings** | SDKs | + | Detected SDKs: [sdk 18], **Project Settings** | **Project** | **SDK: 18**, **Language level: SDK default (18 - No new language features)**; Project Settings | **Modules** | **Sources: Project default (18 - No new language features)**. It worked. Thanks